# How can I call multiple functions at same time in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

```
   $scope.PrintOWTickets = function (TicketNo, MobilNo) {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: $scope.ip + '/getPrintTicekt?TicketNo=' + TicketNo + '&PassengeMobile=' + MobilNo + '&PassengeEmail=' + MobilNo + '&ClientId=' + $scope.clientidFromFactory + ''
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.PrintOW = response.data;
            if (response.data.error == 1) {
                alert("Error");
            }
            else {
                function1(); // if it is success then call function2
                function2();
            }
        })
    };
```

I want to call the second function if the first function returns true.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i understand the question but if you want to call functions synchronously (wait until one function finished) then use the `callback` functions.

```
$scope.PrintOWTickets = function(TicketNo, MobilNo) {
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: $scope.ip + '/getPrintTicekt?TicketNo=' + TicketNo + '&PassengeMobile=' + MobilNo + '&PassengeEmail=' + MobilNo + '&ClientId=' + $scope.clientidFromFactory + ''
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.PrintOW = response.data;
        if (response.data.error == 1) {
            alert("Error");
        } else {
            function1(function() {
                function2();
            }); // if it is success then call function2
        }
    })
};

function function1(callback) {
    console.log("one")
    // do whaterver and return the callback
    callback();
}

function function2() {
    console.log("two")
}
```

```js
function1(function() {
  function2();
});

function function1(callback) {
  console.log("one")
  // do whaterver and return the callback
  callback();
}

function function2() {
  console.log("two")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a normal function you can write

```
if(function1()){
    function2();
}
```

If it is a HTTP or returns promise,

```
function1().then(function(){
    function2();
});
```